# Guidance Required on building a query builder

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, expression-trees, query-builder

I have been tasked with building a querybuilder that allows the user to enter a search term and search 1 field (text) within a database table. The user should be allowed to use 'AND' 'NOT' and 'AND NOT' in the search expression.

I have looked at using an expression tree to do this, but was hoping someone had an example of how this can be easily achieved.

I have found the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

The problem I am having is getting my head around how to find the root of the expression to ensure the left and expression are equal, if there are an odd number of operators it is simple to find the middle, but if there are an even number, should the left be larger? Or the right? Or should I look at the type of operater?

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: No, bit old for homework

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [EasyQuery.NET](http://devtools.korzh.com/query-builder-aspnet/) library.
Seems that's exactly what you need.

Comment: it appears you have been giving this answer quite a bit recently

Comment: Yes, you are right. We are just happy users of that product. I don't have any benefits from such kind of posts if you are hinting at it.

Comment: I will also vouch for EasyQuery.Net, especially for something simple and straightforward. This question is literally why it exists.